# Cells won't load when using multiple collection views

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection views that get their data from two arrays that append from a url session function. I deleted everything and started over and I get that same problem. I added a breakpoint and the arrays are getting filled. I also saw on other solutions, `reloadData()` was used after the array is filled but doesn't work for me

HomeViewController:

```
//Variable declarations
var recentlyPlayed = [RecentlyPlayed]()
private var info = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "parseJSON")
var userLikedSongs = [LikedSongs]()
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!


@IBOutlet weak var LikedSongsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var RecentlyPlayedCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

//Once view has loaded
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Assign Collection views to self
    RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.delegate = self
    RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.dataSource = self
    LikedSongsCollectionView.delegate = self
    LikedSongsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    
    // Get user id and users recently played songs
    let user = getId()
    let id = Int(user)!
    retriveRecentSongs(info: id)
    retriveLikedSongs(info: id)
    RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.reloadData()
    LikedSongsCollectionView.reloadData()

   //Hide navigation bar
   self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true        
    
}

// Define Recent songs collection view count
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(collectionView == RecentlyPlayedCollectionView) {
        return recentlyPlayed.count
    } else {
        return userLikedSongs.count
    }
}
//Set content inside recently collection view cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    if (collectionView == LikedSongsCollectionView) {
        
        let likeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LikedCell", for: indexPath) as! LikedSongsCollectionViewCell
        
        likeCell.LikedData = userLikedSongs[indexPath.row]
        
        return likeCell
    } else {
        let recentCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RecentlyPlayedCell", for: indexPath) as! RecentlyPlayedCollectionViewCell
    
        recentCell.Recentdata = recentlyPlayed[indexPath.row]
        
        return recentCell
    }
}
//Get users recenlty played song with URL session
func retriveRecentSongs(info: Int) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/getRecentlyPlayed.php?info=" + String(info))
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(retrievedList!)
        self.parseRecentSongs(data: retrievedList!)
    }
    .resume()
    print("Getting songs")
}
func parseRecentSongs (data: String) {
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let newSong = RecentlyPlayed(id: itemData[0], songName: itemData[1], trackName: itemData[2], artist: itemData[3], owner: itemData[4], cover: itemData[5])
            recentlyPlayed.append(newSong)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Also can add RecentlyPlayedCollectionViewCell and LikedSongsCollectionView if needed.

Comment: Just a side note you want to name your variables starting with a lowercase, like `@IBOutlet weak var likedSongsCollectionView: UICollectionView!`

Comment: Can you show code for `func retriveRecentSongs(info: id)`?

Comment: Sure I just edited it

Comment: As I suspected. It is an asynchronous functino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `retriveRecentSongs` contains an asynchronous closure. That means code inside it continues to execute even after it's called and returned.

```
func retriveRecentSongs(info: Int) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/getRecentlyPlayed.php?info=" + String(info))

    /// See here!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(retrievedList!)
        self.parseRecentSongs(data: retrievedList!)
    }
    .resume()
    print("Getting songs")
}
```

You might notice how `print("Getting songs")` is printed *before* `print(retrievedList!)`.

When "Getting songs" is printed, you've only just started the `URL` task, and the download hasn't completed yet. At this point, `recentlyPlayed` is **still empty**.

```
retriveRecentSongs(info: id) /// started the download
RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.reloadData() /// but at this point, has not completed yet.
```

You need to call `reloadData` once the download has **finished**.

```
func retriveRecentSongs(info: Int) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/getRecentlyPlayed.php?info=" + String(info))
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(retrievedList!)

        /// ok, the download finished, parse the songs
        self.parseRecentSongs(data: retrievedList!)
    }
    .resume()
    print("Getting songs")
}
func parseRecentSongs (data: String) {
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let newSong = RecentlyPlayed(id: itemData[0], songName: itemData[1], trackName: itemData[2], artist: itemData[3], owner: itemData[4], cover: itemData[5])
            recentlyPlayed.append(newSong)
        }
    }

    /// now, do reloadData.
    RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Also make sure you delete

```
RecentlyPlayedCollectionView.reloadData()
LikedSongsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

inside `viewDidLoad()`.